# How to run Automation api testing with serenity-cucumber bdd using jar file

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, automation-testing

I have a class created for step definitions which uses @Steps annotations from (net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps) for injecting objects. It did work locally but when I ran it through `java -jar` it won't be able to initialize objects annotated with @Steps.

```
public class AutomationRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        JUnitCore.main(CucumberTestSuite.class.getName());
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        snippets = CucumberOptions.SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
        features = "classpath:features",
        tags = "@sometag",
        glue = "com.package.stepdefinitions"
)
public class CucumberTestSuite {
}
```

```
public class Hooks {

    // auto injected by serenity
    private EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables;

    @Steps(shared = true)
    CommonUtilities commonUtilities;
    
    @Before()
    public void before() {
         commonUtilities.someFunc(); // here getting nullpointer
    }

}
```

I was able to generate jar file using `maven-assembly-plugin` to include all files and it executed tests as well but it failed at injecting objects using @steps in stepdefinations.